# What is the correct pom dependency for the below java code?

Tags: java, dependencies, pom.xml, server-sent-events, tomcat8

**Error**

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [org.javaee7.jaxrs.serversentevent.MyApplication] in
>   context with path [/broadcast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] threw exception [Servlet
>   execution threw an exception] with root cause 
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
>     at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**POM.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m13-2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**My tomcat version is 8.0.**

**Java code:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class MyDemo extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyDemo() {
        super(MyResource.class, SseFeature.class);
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEvent;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseBroadcaster;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;


@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    private static final SseBroadcaster BROADCASTER = new SseBroadcaster();

    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput itemEvents() {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        BROADCASTER.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }

    @POST
    public void addItem(e) {

        BROADCASTER.broadcast(new OutboundEvent.Builder().data(String.class, "hello").build());

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you assume there's something wrong with your dependencies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134098/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-uribuilder-uriljava-lang-string

Comment: I tried the above solution. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your error log clearly says what is your problem. It's not problem with your dependency. You trying to call an abstract method `uri`. Check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#uri(java.net.URI)). You will have to find a class which implements this `uri` method.